# Number of zeros of $1-e^{z^k}$ in the complex plane.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $k$ be a positive integer and consider the function $f(z) = 1-e^{z^k}$ in the complex plane. Why is it true that the number of zeros of $f$ in a disk of radius $r$ is about $\pi^{-1}kr^k?$  I tried using Rouche's theorem, but the integral looked quite messy. Is there a better way to see this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

$$1-e^{z^k}=0\iff e^{z^k}=1\iff z^{k}=2m\pi,\quad m\in\mathbb Z$$

Comment: Minor note: There is an i missing in the last equation. (And you just were five seconds quicker than me. ;))

Comment: @Nebr: yes, thank you :-)

Comment: Of course. Thanks!

Comment: Putting $z=re^{i\theta}$ I stopped at $r^k=2m\pi$ for $m\in \mathbb{N}$. I don't know how to conclude that the number of zeros is $\pi^{-1}kr^k.$ I would be very thankful if you give any additional hint.